# SQL 2005 - Search stored procedures for text (Not all text is being searched)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

The following bits of code do not seem to be searching the entire routine definition.

Code block 1:

```
select top 50 * from information_schema.routines
where routine_definition like '%09/01/2008%' and specific_Name like '%NET'
```

Code Block 2:

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%EffectiveDate%' AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE' and ROUTINE_NAME like '%NET'
```

I know for a fact that these bits of SQL work under most circumstances. The problem is this: When I run this for "EffectiveDate" which is buried at line ~800 in a few stored procedures, these stored procedures never show up in the results. It's as if "like" only searches so deep.

Any tips on fixing this?

I want to search the ENTIRE stored procedure for the specified text.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select * 
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE  OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(SPECIFIC_NAME),'IsMSShipped') =0 
       and OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(SPECIFIC_NAME)) like '%EffectiveDate%' 
       AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
       AND ROUTINE_NAME like '%NET'
```

Use the object definition instead.

Comment: Thanks Mastros. What does *OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(SPECIFIC_NAME),'IsMSShipped') =0 * mean?

Comment: By the way, any idea why the above fail?

Comment: Don't know but SQL 2000 had the same issue, where there was 2 ways to retrieve the text of the stored procedure and one was always truncated.

Answer (score 8):

Just to clarify why the [procedure text is truncated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188757.aspx):

> **ROUTINE_DEFINITION  nvarchar(4000)**
>
> Returns **the first 4000 characters** of
>   the definition text of the function or
>   stored procedure if the function or
>   stored procedure is not encrypted.
>   Otherwise, returns NULL.
>
> To ensure that you obtain the complete
>   definition, query the
>   `OBJECT_DEFINITION` function or the
>   definition column in the
>   `sys.sql_modules` catalog view.

Answer (score 2):

Here's different approach if you are looking for a search feature against the SQL server databases. Basically the freely available search tool from RedGate.

[Free 'Search' from Redgate](http://chathurangaw.blogspot.com/2010/04/power-up-sql-management-studio-with.html)

Answer (score 0):

very fast,live and handy
Direct link
http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Search/index.htm