# Search stored procedures/functions in all databases

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to search for specific text in all procedures/functions etc. in all databases. I managed to create the required query from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217930/sql-2005-search-stored-procedures-for-text-not-all-text-is-being-searched/1217937#1217937) but it looks like OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(SPECIFIC_NAME)) returns NULL for all DBs except the current one.

```
sp_msforeachdb 'SELECT ''?'' AS DB, SPECIFIC_NAME, OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(SPECIFIC_NAME)) FROM [?].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is OBJECT_ID cannot be used that way.  It only works on the current database.  Try returning ROUTINE_DEFINITION directly from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES.  This does have a limit of 4000 characters.  I'll try to find my other answer on SO which gives my workaround using the MS metadata views.

Have a look at this:

[Can you search SQL Server 2005 Stored Procedure content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466130/can-you-search-sql-server-2005-stored-procedure-content/466188#466188)

Answer (score 12):

You absolutely need Red-Gate's **[SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Search/index.htm)** tool - it's **FREE**, and absolutely great and perfectly suited for this need.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
select * from syscomments where [text] like '%yourKeyword%'
```